# Why does sudo require a password the second time in a bash script every time?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I have a simple very tiny web app, and wanted to make my life a bit easier by having a very simplistic deployment script, that does the following:

1. Pull updates from git
2. Run composer
3. Change owner of all files

The script basically works fine and looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Updating repository ...";
sudo git pull;

echo "Installing composer dependencies from lockfile ...";
composer install;

echo "Changing owner to www-data:www-data ...";
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data .;

echo "Deployment DONE!";
```

However, as you can see, I have two commands run as sudo in this script. Nameply the `git pull` and the `chown`.

My problem is as follows: I am aware that there is a timeout for how often the system asks for my password when running commands with sudo. The problem is, that, even though I am well within the timeout, the script **always** asks for the password on the **second** sudo (chown) command.

Could someone please enlighten me, why that may be the case?

Comment: You know lines don't *need* to end with `;`s, right? You just like it 'cause you're a Real C Programmer who eats pointers to pointers to pointers to pointers for breakfast?

Comment: @cat Yes I know. I like doing it like that because it looks "cleaner" to me *shrug

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know what's the reason, however there's solution:

```
if [[ $(id -u $(whoami)) != 0 ]]
then
    sudo bash $( cd $(dirname $0) ; pwd -P )
    # taken from http://stackoverflow.com/a/4774063/2797066
else
    #rest of script
fi
```

Comment: The script asks for the password on the second sudo command because Composer always calls `sudo -k`, invalidating the user's cached credentials. An environment variable, COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER, may be used to disable automatic clearing of sudo sessions. Make sure you understand the security implications before using this. See

[https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser).

Comment: @TooManyPets Your comment should be an answer, it's a clear explanation with a tip how to fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you run script with `sudo` like this:

```
sudo bash /path/to/script.sh
```

Where `script.sh` has following content with no `sudo`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Updating repository ...";
git pull;

echo "Installing composer dependencies from lockfile ...";
composer install;

echo "Changing owner to www-data:www-data ...";
chown -R www-data:www-data .;

echo "Deployment DONE!"
```

This way script will only ask you for password for 1 time.

Comment: I thought about that too. However I want to avoid running composer with sudo, as this is discouraged. Thats why I don't want to run the whole script with sudo.